# Suggest a better way of using this conditional statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there any better way of checking this piece of code,

```
if (is_string($test) && $test != NULL) {
    $test = 'yes';
} else {
    $test = null;
}
```

And

```
 if (is_null($test) || !isset($this->_status[$test])) {
    $icon = null;
} else {
    $icon = $this->getImage($this->_status[$test]);
}
```

Comment: if `$test` is a string, it's not a null.

Comment: @Andrew: this is incorrect. It could be a string, and still evaluate to NULL (an empty string for instance).  You would have been absolutely right with `!==`.

Comment: @JayTaph Yep, correct, didn't pay attention. Removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Better way you mean by reducing line of codes? How about using ternary operator.

```
$test = is_string($test) ? "Yes" : NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorthand if/else using Ternary Operator

```
$test = (is_string($test) and $test != NULL) ? 'yes' : null;
$icon = (is_null($test) or ! isset($this->_status[$test])) ? null : $this->getImage($this->_status[$test]);
```